# Can't access state object from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

so I am trying to access the values I get back from my backend server. The data is being updated as it should in Redux, but somehow I can't access it in the render function. 
The problem is that with `this.props.account` returns and object. But when I try to access anything inside of it, for example `this.props.account.role` it says undefined. But shown by the object before, it should say USER

This is my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Loading} from '../components/helpers/Loading.component';
import {Navbar} from '../components/navigation/Navigation.component';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {fetchAccount} from '../actions/index.action';

export class Account extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchAccount;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Loading isLoading={!this.props.account}>
                <Navbar />
                {console.log(this.props.account)}
            </Loading>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    account: state.account.account
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchAccount: dispatch(fetchAccount())
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Account)
```

This is where I dispatch

```
export const fetchAccount = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(conf.http + '://' + conf.host + '/api/account', {
            headers: {
                "token": localStorage.getItem('token')
            },
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(data => (data.json())
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(receiveAccount(res))
            }));
    }
}
```

The reducer

```
export const account = (state = [], action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_ACCOUNT':
        return {
            ...state,
            account: action.payload
        };
    default:
        return state; 
    }
}
```

and rootReducer

```
import { tickets } from './ticket.reducer';
import { account } from './account.reducer';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

export default combineReducers({
    tickets,
    account
});
```

Comment: Put `console.log(this.props.account)` before your return in `render()` and let us know what you get. Also, you're missing `componentWillReceiveProps` which will allow the component to get the new data after the promise is resolved

Comment: When I do that it returns undefined. If I console.log this.props I can see the account object, but cant go into it. What should I do in the receiveProps, just add it or does It require some code?

Answer (score 1):

For what you describe in your question, you are trying to access an array of objects like this:

```
accounts = [
 {
  name: 'Jimbo',
  id: 1
  role: 'player',
 },
 {
  name: 'James',
  id: 2,
  role: 'employee'
 },
]
```

When you state `this.props.account.role`. You are trying to access a property, which indeed, does not exist.

You can try something like, filtering the array (A), the specific index that you want to access(B), or map trough the array(C).

**A:**`this.props.accounts.find(account => acount.role === 'player')`

**B:**`this.props.accounts[0].role`

**C:**`this.props.accounts.map(role => <li>{account.role}</li>)`

Comment: It's actually not an array it's just a object with one user in it, so I think it's strange that I somehow not being able to access it this way.

Comment: What about using `Object.kets(this.props.accounts)`, that should return a list of all the enumerable props of `this.props.accounts`.

Comment: When I do the `Object.keys(this.props)`, I see the account. When I then do it on the account as well, the console logs this error: `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

I thought it could have to do with me doing the `data.json()` in my action, and therefor its just a plain json object. But doing `JSON.parse(data)` would tell that it is already an object.

Comment: I tried accessing it in the reducer by doing `console.log(action.payload.userId)` and that works totally fine. Which brings this down to the link between view and reducer

Comment: It might have something to do with the type of component and the binding. When you `consle.log(this.props)`, what does it show? Could you try a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props, null, 2))` on the `render()` method and share it with me?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else reaching this post, check to make sure you're not trying to drill into the payload before the state is actually updated. - That was my issue.